# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor - How to conditionally quit or end or return or break a partial view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

With Razor, how do you conditionally quit or end or return or break a partial view?

```
@if (Model == null)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: You're already answering the question with your example. It's valid and does work. Duplicate and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742865/abort-skip-cancel-the-rendering-of-a-razor-view

Answer (score 11):

No, you don't `return` in a view, you simply don't include such partial in the main view:

```
@if (Model != null) {
    @Html.Partial("somePartial", Model)
}
```

or if you use `RenderPartial`:

```
@if (Model != null) {
    @{Html.RenderPartial("somePartial", Model);}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Invert the if:

```
<p>html that I always want</p>
@if (Model != null)
{
      your html when model != null
}
```