# Abort/skip/cancel the rendering of a Razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Many devs do this:

```
public void foo() {
  if (flag) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I prefer to "return early", and so do this instead:

```
public void foo() {

  if (!flag) return;

  // do stuff

}
```

In an ASP.NET-MVC Razor view, what is the correct way to abort/skip/cancel rendering of a view/partialview? For example how do I convert this:

```
@if (flag) {
  // do stuff
}
```

to something like this:

```
@if (!flag) { /* what do I do here to abort/skip/cancel the rendering? */ }

// do stuff
```

I've tried using `return` and playing with the `Request`, but am unsure how this affects the process. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You do not _abort_ page rendering (unless you want to throw exceptions because of fatal errors). Logic has to stay in controller, view shouldn't have anything else than `if (flag) {}` to include/exclude sections according to controller's decisions (and even that may be done better with partial views).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti True. Perhaps "abort" is the wrong word. But question remains.

Comment: If with "abort" you mean you want to exclude something according to that flag then you have nothing to do, just use `if` to delimit such sections (eventually it may even be from that line to the end of file). Quickly it'll become hard to understand so you may use **partial views** for that. If you need to drop/skip/cancel page creation (for example to redirect to another page or to display something completely different) then **you're doing that check in the wrong place. Do it in your controller**, it'll pick right view and views won't be aware of such logic.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti All true. But I still want to code this way. There are always going to be conditional structures in views, it's unavoidable. The rendering is not magic, there is some component in Razor that reads the view and spits our HTML--there must be a way to return early in that process.

Comment: As a general programming guideline, multiple exit points *are a bad thing* as the code must be read sequentially, in its entirety,  to understand the program flow. It is generally clearer to use nested `if`s.

Comment: @hbob Actually, the view gets compiled into a class (when the application starts up I believe), and then later on a method in the class get executed during the rendering pipeline - it doesn't work quite the way you think I suspect, and hopefully explains why there is no way to return early from a Razor view...

Comment: @hbob you may want it but you can't (and actually also you shouldn't).

Comment: Try returning an EmptyResult() from ActionFilter. If you still want to do at view level then probably you split views - however you will still need condition to check.

Comment: @codebased EmptyResult() is still something that has to be done in controller. In views you can _invoke_ another view with Response.Redirect() but you can't replace current view (but you may include it as partial view).

Comment: That is what I meant when I said if you want to do at view level then probably split and check whatever condition.

Comment: @codebased understood!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Disagree. It's no a guideline at all, it's a matter of style. "Returning early" is well established. Lot of devs code that way. We do. Avoiding a mess of conditionals is a *good thing* as it makes reading your code easy. If you contend that it makes code hard to read, then perhaps your function is too long to begin with.

Comment: @RB Yes I suspected that, but hoped there was some internal mechanism to return early. Please add your comment as an answer - it's the only one that actually answers the question.

Comment: @h bob: The problem of multiple exit points is well documented and leads to more maintenance problems than not. Any function-length issues are irrelevant as you would normally factor out worker code an leave only decision making. You are of course free to code as you wish, including going against the designed use of MVC views. I was only pointing out potential future problems, but as I don't have to maintain it I will simply say good luck :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie For every "study" you show me which claims that returning early is bad, I'll see you and raise you a "study" showing it's good. Like I said, it's a matter of style and preference. Besides, this matter is only tangential to the question.

Comment: As I said... *I* don't have to maintain it, so good luck :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Fair dinkum ;)

Comment: We don't all speak like that (i.e. *strewth mate, that's a load of dingo's kidneys*) :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As I mentioned above, you can simply issue a `return`.

I recall cshtml files are compiled at runtime, which includes all inline code as well as the static html. That means that in theory, I'd expect any code to be left as-is and not transformed in any way.

So if you do this:

```
@if (!flag) { return; }

// do stuff
```

It *works as expected* (well for me at least). I just wanted to know if this leads to any unintended side-effects.

Comment: +1 My upvote but I wouldn't use it in any page (returning early is good IMO if you have 20 lines function but - usually - a cshtml page is longer and more convoluted, exactly the reasons single return point has been in use in the past). Anyway upvoted, even if I don't appreciate it, because I didn't even know it may work! With a quick look using Reflector to disassemble generated code it seems OK without (visible) side-effects.

Comment: +1 for "you learn something new every day", but yeah - don't think I'm ever gonna use this one ;-)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for understanding! What you said above is true and I follow it 99% of the time. But in programming as in life, there is always the 1% and so it's good to understand the environment and be experienced enough to bend the rules without breaking the system. Didn't think of disassembling to see what happens, grazie!

Comment: @hbob if you find something interesting there please update your post, with a quick look it simply seems that return simply exits rendering function but I didn't see/check with _exotic_ features and/or with or without layouts.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : Early in my career as a developer I always tried to have one (or two) "return" points in my methods/members. Because that's what everyone was told to do. Turns out that trying to achieve that ends up creating WAY too much code nesting.You really shouldn't alter or sacrifice reasonable code flow just to achieve that obsolete principal. In modern programming, the consensus is that if you can exit a method, do it. And the sooner the better. And there is no need to even count how many returns you have, as long as your focus is to reduce code nesting. Anyway, my $0.02.

Comment: @paul I completely agree with that (that's why I said _it has been in use in the past_), HTML pages are however a different story because we suppose to...do not have _return_ at all. In this specific case, it might well be an exception but I still think that if you do it constantly then there is something else broken in the design (again, in HTML not in _code_).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : Ah, I see. Sorry, I must have misunderstood. But yeah I agree that the concept of "returning" or "exiting" in Html doesn't seem to make sense. Its probably better to describe it as a process of scanning text input, line by line. And if the "processor" decides it needs to stop scanning, it "exits" or halts its current execution and "returns" what it had processed up until that point.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti (continued): What actually brought me to this question was I ran across a Razor MVC page that had the entire body (everything under usings and model declaration) wrapped in an if statement. So I told the developer to flip the if statement and just do a return if it fails the boolean evaluation in order to cut down on nesting. So I just wanted to make sure I was telling him to do something that was actually possible in Razor.

Comment: I see, maybe it's possible to refactor that component out or to pick between two different views (leaving this responsibility to the controller instead of the view) but yeah, definitely if it's not possible or simply too costly then it's better than nesting!

Answer (score 7):

If with *"abort"* you mean you want to exclude something according to that flag then you have nothing to do, just use `if` to delimit such sections (eventually it may even be from that line to the end of file). Like this:

```
 @if (Model.User.HasEditingPrivileges)
 {
     <input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit"/>
 }
```

Quickly it'll become hard to understand so you may use **partial views** for that (especially if blocks you have to include/exclude are big):

```
 @if (Model.User.HasEditingPrivileges)
 {
     Html.RenderPartial("EditSection");
 }
```

If you need to drop/skip/cancel page creation (for example to redirect to another page or to display something completely different), like this:

```
@if (!Model.User.hasEditingPrivileges)
{
    // Ooops, he shouldn't see this page, go back to Home!
}
```

Then **you're doing that check in the wrong place**. Do it in your controller, it'll pick right view and views won't be aware of such logic:

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
    if (HasUserEditingPrivileges)
        return View("Edit", new MyModel(id));

    return Redirect("UnauthorizedAccess"); // Oops, something went wrong
}
```

Why not?

- Because views shouldn't be aware of such logic. If you need something like that (CGI like sequential flow) then you shouldn't use MVC because it adds a complexity you don't need.
- Because you can't (unless someone find a terrible dirty hacky trick). MVC is structured to build a page when it has to be displayed (controller decides which page and with which data). When this building starts an output is required (unless you throw an exception to signal an error but you should really avoid exceptions to handle program flow then...). For small ifs you may simply use first mentioned method.

To summarize:

> In an ASP.NET-MVC Razor view, what is the correct way to abort rendering of a view/partialview?

There is not a correcty way because you must not do it. Code in view has to render the page, it has not to decide which page should be sent to client. If you're doing anything else then you're [using MVC as it shouldn't be used](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix.aspx), it's just not correct.

Comment: I agree with all you've mentioned. And code that way too, almost always. But sometime I want to do what I've described above. I'm +1 you though, as I agree with what you've written in principle.

Comment: What about partial views? There's no action method for a partial, it's not called from controller. And "early returns" might still be needed